# Frustrating remote control issue 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vnc

I have recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and I'm now having difficulty utilizing remote control tools to connect to my desktop.  At first, I though it was the immaturity of Teamviewer, but now I'm having a very similar issue using RealVNC.

For some reason, the RealVNC server is unable to connect to the cloud, and I see that the service iterates at increasingly longer delays.  I have checked using uwf and no firewall is active.  No other network configuration changes have been made.  I am not using Wayland.

Comment: Could be related to the switch to OpenSSL 3.0 mentioned in the [release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668). There is no useful info to go by, so let's guess.

Comment: Searching the logs, i see this error message: Lookup for Discovery service failed: Hosted Discovery error: HTTP Unauthorized